# NSData to NSString conversion adding newline characters

Tags: php, objective-c, nsdata

My iOS app uses an NSURLConnection to retrieve the contents of a php web page (which is encoded as UTF-8) and save it as an NSData object. For the sake of testing this page is a single word:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo "Test";
```

The app then converts this to an NSString using the following code:

```
mystring = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The content of the page is being saved successfully, but newline characters (\n) are added to the beginning and end of the the string:

```
\nTest\n
```

I could just replace these characters but I'd prefer to avoid them completely. Why might the \n characters be added and how can I avoid them?